# Display a label covering the whole UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I'd like to display a big fat label overlayed on top of my UITableView if there are no elements to be displayed. (This label would provide instructions on how to add elements.) I wonder what the best method would be to achieve this.

I tried dragging a UIView on my UITableView. I thought I could add labels there and then set the `.hidden` property programmatically. However, it seems to be tricky to embed the UIView in the UITableView using IB.

Is it possible to create the label programmatically and have it cover a big chunk of my UITableView (i.e., not just be in a particular cell of the table)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to add a special overlay view for this purpose.

you can do this by assigning the created label to the property `self.tableView.backgroundView` in the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` method of the `UITableViewDelegate`

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  if (loans) { // check if the data is present or not

    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
    return 1;

  } else { // if not present

    // Display a message when the table is empty
    UILabel *messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];

    messageLabel.text = @"No data is currently available.";
    messageLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    messageLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    messageLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino-Italic" size:20];//
    [messageLabel sizeToFit];

    self.tableView.backgroundView = messageLabel;
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do it yourself: https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNEmptyDataSet

Otherwise create a label programmatically and add it like this:

```
let myLabel = UILabel(frame: myTableView.frame)
myLabel.text = "Hello World"
self.view.addSubview(myLabel)
myTableView.hidden = true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just provide insructions and then want to remove overlayed view or any.

1. Create View

> var DynamicView=UIView(frame: self.view.frame) DynamicView.alpha = 0.5
>   self.view.addSubview(DynamicView)

2. Add Label to DynamicView at position where you want....
3. Add tapGesture to dismiss/hide view.

> var tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:
>   "tapDetected") self.
>   DynamicView.alpha.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

create `"tapDetected"` method and write code to hide DynamicView

Comment: Adding the gesture recognizer to the `alpha` value (a primitive type) leads to a compiling error. You can only add the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your **DynamicView**